# BootstrapValidator turn off enabled and disabled the submit button when typing

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

How can always enable submit button when typing in BootstrapValidator?

Comment: There isn't any aim to do it if you want to use BV. Don't use it if you want to achieve your goal

Comment: BootstrapValidator was done to protect submit button from empty input. Once all input are validated, submit button will be enable ...

Comment: Ok, but When I am typing, the submit button enabled/disabled alternatively, it is not usability

Comment: Sorry I hadn't understood the right question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To achieve your goal, [follow this tutorial](http://bootstrapvalidator.com/examples/enabling-submit-button/) from bootstrapvalidator.com

```
  $('#alwaysEnableButtonForm')
      .bootstrapValidator({
          ...
      })
      .on('error.field.bv', function(e, data) {
          if (data.bv.getSubmitButton()) {
              data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
          }
      })
      .on('success.field.bv', function(e, data) {
          if (data.bv.getSubmitButton()) {
              data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
          }
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#validationForm').bootstrapValidator();
$('#validationForm').on('error.field.bv', function(e, data) {
        // $(e.target)  --> The field element
        // data.bv      --> The BootstrapValidator instance
        // data.field   --> The field name
        // data.element --> The field element

        data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
    });
    $('#validationForm').on('success.field.bv', function(e, data) {
        // e, data parameters are the same as in error.field.bv event handler
        // Despite that the field is valid, by default, the submit button will be disabled if all the following conditions meet
        // - The submit button is clicked
        // - The form is invalid
        data.bv.disableSubmitButtons(false);
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#site_ekle_form').data('bootstrapValidator').resetForm();
```

Comment: Please add some explanation to your answer. Code-only answers are usually marked as low-quality posts and are frowned upon.